# Efficiently inserting a decimal in perl string

Tags: perl

I came across code:

```
sub insertDecimal
{
        my $number = shift;
        my $sigDigRight = shift;

        if ($number =~ /\./) { return ($number); }
        elsif (length $number < $sigDigRight) { return ($number); }
        else
        {
                my $leftSide = substr($number, 0, (length $number)-$sigDigRight);
                my $rightSide = substr($number, (length $number)-$sigDigRight, );

                return ($leftSide . "." . $rightSide);
        }
}
```

And I hoped to improve/re-write as:

```
sub insertDecimal
{
        my ($number, $sigDigRight) = @_;

        return $number if index ($number, '.') != -1 or length $number < $sigDigRight;

        # YES! substr takes an LVALUE ... perldoc it for more :)
        substr($number, -$sigDigRight, 0) = '.';

        return $number;
}
```

I was very surprised that a run of some 74mm records had almost no improvement at all with 2nd version.

Questions:

1. Anyone to *overflow* with better way to make insertDecimal more efficient ?
2. How come I see no improvement, at all (just one minute better on 74MM records) ?
3. If Perl compiler is re-jiggering the code of the first version to be more efficient, is there anyway I can see the improved path to execution that Perl has chosen ?

Comment: Can you describe what each version is intended to do, and provide some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: `just one minute better on 74MM records` - How long does the first subroutine take?

Comment: Also, note `perl -E '$x = 1234; substr($x, -2, 0, "."); say $x'` ... I am not sure your comment is needed.

Comment: Why are you "inserting a decimal" instead of just dividing by a multiple of 10 if the value is an int?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Maybe a healthy desire to avoid any kind of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @SinanÜnür That makes sense. It just seems odd to write a roundabout division function and expect it to perform well.

Comment: Please describe in English what your subroutine is supposed to do (including edge cases)

Comment: *"a run of some 74mm records"* Those are short records — just under three inches

Comment: @ysth - I prefer interpretive dance.

Comment: This said `insertDecimal` is just a helper routine, part of working on a 74-million-line fix-record file. The overall goal is to parse desired fields to a CSV file. My overall goal was/is to speed up the task (which was taking some 105 minutes [and now is down to 30 and could be faster the more CPU's the machine has _(yes threaded!)_)

Comment: In this question, I simply wanted to focus on `insertDecimal`, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both routines would seem to do essentially the same amount of work:

- scan `$number` for a single character (any compiler ought be able to reduce that regex match to an `index`)
- compare the length of `$number` to a limit
- possibly insert a single character somewhere within `$number`

Using lvalue `substr` (or, just taking advantage of the fourth argument to `substr`) may make the insertion a little more efficient, but, after all, things will have to be moved.

To my eye, the biggest opportunity for optimization comes from moving the length check ahead of the check for the decimal point.

I would be tempted to re-write your routine as

```
sub insertDecimal {
    my ($number, $sigDigRight) = @_;

    return $number if length($number) < $sigDigRight;
    return $number if index($number, '.') >= 0;

    substr($number, -$sigDigRight, 0, '.');

    $number;
}
```

I find simple decisions and short lines to be easier to understand. I do not think this should change the correctness of the function.

An ugly alternative is:

```
sub gah {
    my ($number, $sigDigRight) = @_;

    my $n = length($number) - $sigDigRight;
    return $number unless $n > 0;

    $number =~ s{\A ([^.]{$n}) ([^.]+) \z}{$1.$2}x;
    $number;
}
```

That combines the check for `.` with the replacement operation.

Again, I cannot be certain this is correct wrt your spec, but it is something for you to explore.

I probably would not opt for `gah` unless the improvement was more than 20% of something that took at least an hour or so. On my system, it slows down a simple example by 1,000%.

Comment: gah? Am I dense, or is that a typo?

Comment: Okay. You scared me for a minute. :-)

Comment: I wonder if both routines _indeed_ do essentially the *same* amount of work? They do the same *thing*, but to me it seemed that the first does more weight lifting (with the 2 `substr` calls). Also, please explain why you think _moving the length check ahead of the check for the decimal point_ would help to optimize (considering that in most cases this routine would run all the way)?

Comment: And yes I agree the ugly alternative, is hmm, well, ugly :) However, it does show your TIMTOWTDI skills! However, I don't see why that would improve performance considering that `([^.]{$n})` of the regex needs to be recompiled with each `gah` call?